# how can I save a file after cropping?

Tags: android, image, crop

I am creating an android application. It takes a picture then allows you to crop it and then displays it. Problem is that it only saves the taken image not the cropped one. Basically i need it to save the cropped image. how can I save a file after cropping?

Code:

```
private void performCrop(){
    //take care of exceptions
    try {
        //call the standard crop action intent (the user device may not support it)
        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP"); 
        //indicate image type and Uri
        cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
        //set crop properties
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        //indicate aspect of desired crop
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1.5);
        //indicate output X and Y
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
        //retrieve data on return
        cropIntent.putExtra("return", true);
        //start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);  

    }

    //respond to users whose devices do not support the crop action
    catch(ActivityNotFoundException anfe){
        //display an error message 
        String errorMessage = "Your device does not support cropping";
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: How can i make it save the cropped image?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Unfortunately, what you're asking is  an *extremely* broad question with an entire book's worth of answers.  Stackoverflow is for very specific programming questions.  What have you tried doing, and what isn't working?

Answer (score 3):

Just add something like this:

```
    try{    
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES 
            ), fileName+".png"); //save to your pictures folder
     outputFileURI = Uri.fromFile(file);

     cropIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileURI);
     startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP); 
    } catch (IOException ioe){ 
        // handle your exception
     }
```

Remember to refresh the gallery after saving so that its instantly available in the gallery. So use this code maybe in your onActivityResult method?

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse
                    ("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

**Edit:** Found a better way to refresh the gallery since sendBroadcast can be a inefficient if you are just refreshing for one image. Use a MediaScanner to scan the file like so

```
Intent intent =   new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE); 
                intent.setData(outputFileURI); // Add the path to the file
                sendBroadcast(intent);
```

This will just scan for the new file and refresh that instead of the whole gallery.